# How to add sudo for a debug configuration in Eclipse, in Ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, configuration, ubuntu, sudo

In eclipse for a particular debug configuration I need to put "sudo" before the executable in order to gain root privileges.

Is there a way to do this rather than launching eclipse with sudo?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your java application with root privilege, then attach the process to debug.

```
sudo java -jar xxx.jar -vmargs -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
```

attach the localhost:8000 to debug your app in eclipse